# Timezone Conversion in Snowflake

Tags: sql, powerbi, dbeaver, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need help in converting timezones in snowflake.
The below query works fine in snowflake worksheets but not in BI tools like Power BI. Its giving local time i.e IST

select
convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', current_timestamp())

Please help

Thanks,
Yogs